# FFTPACK in C examples

Tags: c, fft

I'm trying to use FFTPACK converted from Fortran to C that I downloaded from Netlib (http://www.netlib.org/fftpack/). Unfortunately it seems to not really documented, and very cryptic (as I imagine most FFT codes are). Apparently it should follow a similar structure to the original Fortran code, so that's what I tried.

Here's what I have so far:

```
void main()
{
   int n = 10;
   float* wsave;

   forward_transform(function1, wsave, n);
}

void forward_transform(float (*f)(float), float* wsave, int n)
{
     int *ifac;
     int i;
     float r[n];

     for (i = 0; i< n; i++)//set function values
     {
        r[i] = f((float)(-M_PI + i*2*M_PI/(n-1)));
     }

    __ogg_fdrffti(n, *wsave, *ifac);//initialize    
    __ogg_fdrfftf(n, *r, *wsave, *ifac);//forward transform
}
```

This code manages to compile, but gives a segfault when I call `__ogg_fdrffti`. I tried entering via gbd into fft.c to see exactly where the error is, but I can't seem to do that (the code still segfaults at the same line in my forward_transform function) leading me to believe that I'm somehow making an error in how I'm passing the various arrays.

Does anyone have any experience with or examples of the C version of FFTPACK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables initialized in these functions have to exist somewhere in memory. You are passing pointers instead.

Try

```
void main()
{
   int n = 10;
   float wsave;

   forward_transform(function1, wsave, n);
}

void forward_transform(float (*f)(float), float wsave, int n)
{
     int ifac;
     int i;
     float r[n];

     for (i = 0; i< n; i++)//set function values
     {
        r[i] = f((float)(-M_PI + i*2*M_PI/(n-1)));
     }

    __ogg_fdrffti(n, &wsave, &ifac);//initialize    
    __ogg_fdrfftf(n, r, &wsave, &ifac);//forward transform
}
```

Notice that the pointers are created using the address operator `&` on actual variables.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to help a bit. If I also change `*r` to `&r` I can at least enter into the ftt functions. Now the first call works fine, but in the second call I get a seg fault. Entering gdb at line 31 (first call to fft) I can print r and get an array of numbers, but at line 32 (second fft call) when I print r it returns a memory address. If I ask what's at that memory address *r, I get the error "cannot access memory at address 0x...". Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @HH Sorry, I should have spotted that. Just use `r`. The array name is already a pointer to the array.

Comment: `ifac` must be an array